# CKEditor separate the toolbar from the editor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor on a project where space for the instances is constrained to the point that it would be useful to have a remote toolbar in some fixed position, similar to TinyMCE or nicEdit.

Has anyone managed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question using Shared Spaces lets you do what I wanted.  I found the example here.

http://vtk.ugent.be/best/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/_samples/sharedspaces.html

Comment: Hey, I have been trying to use the shared spaces plugin but getting the following error:
[CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "sharedspace" was not found at `"https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.4/full/plugins/sharedspace/plugin.js?t=F969".(anonymous function) @ ckeditor.js:231g @ ckeditor.js:226z @ ckeditor.js:226A @ ckeditor.js:226CKEDITOR.env.ie.CKEDITOR.env.version.f.$.onerror @ ckeditor.js:227`

My ckeditor build has the plugin included in it. Any idea why am I seeing this?