# Separate Toolbar for Inline editing CKEditor 4

Tags: generics, ckeditor, toolbar, shared, spaces

I have multiple **CKEditor 4** instances running with inline editing (`contenteditable="true"`). By default this opens the toolbar next to the instance every time I'm editing.

The intended functionality is **having a generic toolbar on a specific place** without using css positioning, therefore controlling the active instance that is being edited.
(Ideally by setting the target parent for the toolbar)

I have read about **Shared Spaces** but I found they are only available for *CKEditor 3*, as mentioned here [CKEditor separate the toolbar from the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567164/ckeditor-separate-the-toolbar-from-the-editor)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available yet in CKEditor v4. We're planning to implement it in 4.1 - here's the ticket http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9387.